# Visual Studio-debugging in "observation" window returns strange results

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I've noticed that I can enter variables in the observation window to show them(as help for debugging).

I've tried some stuff and noticed that I can enter single line commands there, which is a really nice tool to check complicated if's...

In my recent project I noticed a really strange behaviour.
     [image: Click on the Picture to enlarge]

the code written in the editor window works fine....
but strangely it doesn't work in the observe "windows"(sorry, I'm not sure how it is called correctly).

There it says (translated)...

> "System.Array" contains no definition for "Contains", and it was found no extension method 'Contains "that takes a first argument of type' System.Array". (Missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have seriously no clue why this happens.

Comment: Yes. Completely expected. The debugger does not understand extension methods. I believe the was added to VS2015 though.

Comment: well, but stuff like `"heey".Substring(0,1)` works perfectly -.- or did I got something wrong?

Comment: Substring is not an extension method.

Comment: @leppie ... thanks, I'm sorry for my missing knowledge:)